# Node http.request HEAD issue

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

Having a problem with making a lot of requests with method 'HEAD'.

I've made async.queue set to 20, and timeout to 3000ms.
Anyway when i run:
I see 10-15 success, than some timouts with some more success, an hangs... nothing happening further.

If i remove timeout i have about 10 success and hang...
And i dont get the error message neither.

The Code of request:

```
function getHeader(link)
{  
  var correctUrl = url.parse(link);  
  var options = {method: 'HEAD', host: correctUrl.hostname, port: 80, path: correctUrl.pathname};  
  var req = http.request(options, function(res) {   
    if(res.statusCode == 404 || res.statusCode == 500) return;      
    var x = {
      loc : link     
    };  

    if(typeof(res.headers['last-modified']) != "undefined") 
    {
      x.lastmod = dateConverter(res.headers['last-modified']);      
      console.log("Added lastmodify: " + x.lastmod);
    }
    console.log(res.headers);    
    parser.allObjects.push(x);    
  });  

  req.setTimeout(3000, function() {
    console.log("Timeout reached. Link:" + link);
    req.abort();
  });

  req.on('error', function (e) {
    console.log('problem with request: ' + e.message);
  });

  req.end();
}
```

And the queue is here:

```
var queue = async.queue(function (href, callback) {
  getHeader(href,function(err){
    if(err) return callback(err);
    return callback();
  });
}, parser.serverMight); // this set to 20 at the mom (decreased from 50)

queue.drain = function() {
  formXml(null, parser.allObjects);
};

queue.push(toRequest, function(err) {
  if(err) console.log(err);
});
```

Any help is highly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Just had a try to switch to httpreq. And i've got exactly 20 (the same as queue) success and hang. I believe the next cycle of queue doesn't start, just to get why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heh, found myself. Maybe this may help someone.
So the mistake was very simple: 
I didn't callback from the getHeader function, i just used return. That's why the queue couldn't start the next round. 
Httpreq takes less space, so i i'll let it stay.

Here is how the correct code look:

```
function getHeader(link, callback)
{   
  httpreq.get(link, function(err, res) {      
    if(err) return callback(err);
    if(res.statusCode == 404 || res.statusCode == 500)
    {
      parser.allHrefs.remove(parser.allHrefs.indexOf(link));
      console.log("Faced status code 404 || 500. url deleted: " + link);
      return callback(null);
    }
    //collect header-info
    var x = { loc : link };
    if(typeof(res.headers['last-modified']) != "undefined")     
      x.lastmod = dateConverter(res.headers['last-modified']);      

    console.log("Success adding header:" + x.loc);
    parser.allObjects.push(x);
    return callback(null);
  });   
}
```

p.s.: somewhy the 'httpreq' (requesting full request body) is making this faster, than 'http' (requesting HEAD)...